# VSCode move selection of multiple lines up and down

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to get used to VSCode because of dendron and I am friend of learning defaults because I work on too many installs to maintain custom settings.

Is there any equivalent in VSCode to sublime text multiline movement?

I have attached a GIF to show what I mean because I can't seem to find the right google keywords or everyone else means something else than me with saying move multiple cursor lines vertically.

In ST I can move them after selecting them with a cursor via SHIFT + CTRL + Up/Down

[GIF of st3 multi line movement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDcyU.gif)

EDIT: Found it. Sublime Text 3 can move blocks by cursor, vscode can't. It only moves by selection. Which ironically work with a single line cursor though.

Comment: alt+cursorUpDown

Comment: This unfortunately only moves one line for me. Is it supposed to move all cursors?

Comment: if the cursors are on consecutive lines only the first lines moves, if there are lines in-between they all move, if you want to move a block text use a single cursor select and Alt+cursorUpDown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select all lines which you want to move up/down then Alt + (arrow key up/ arrow key down ) to move your piece of code up or down.